# What mechanism can I use to calculate/display text output based on (possibly multiple) related child objects on custom object

Tags: formula-field, screen-flow

Please forgive me if there's a related post, but I couldn't find one. As the title suggests, I have a custom object (A) that will be the parent side of a lookup relationship and I am looking for a way to have a text output display (think like formula field, but, as far as I can tell, formula fields cannot reference child fields, only parent) on the parent of that record (B) (which shouldn't be an issue as long as I can calculate the value and stick it in a field on A).

To make this less confusing, the context of this is displaying a different/slightly modified call script depending upon which child objects (think medication/supplements) are related to the account. What is on display doesn't even have to be a field - it just has to display on the account record.

I looked at using screen flows and I don't think it seems to be the correct mechanism. Am I looking at using a lightning web component/visual force page here? I was hoping to not have to custom code it if I could help it.

Thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) or a record-triggered Flow

Comment: Do you need this field to be in, for example, reports? Or, just when you're viewing a record?

Comment: Just when viewing a record. We don't need this field in reports.

Comment: You have a number of no code solutions you can use. You could build a report and put it on the parent's page, or use the built-in Related Records component, or even use a single page screen flow. Even if you needed Visualforce, you can write it all without any Apex in just a few lines of code. The main limitation would be how you want the data presented.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm curious about having a text output based on a report and putting it on the parent page - wouldn't the report just show the related (child) records....were you thinking of using formula fields within the report? Could I calculate a (single) text output based on multiple different child records?

Comment: I'm just curious why it needs to be "one field". A report on a page layout would look much like a related list, a list of records with whatever fields you wanted to show, but it sounds like you want something else. What is this field for, how will it be used? This question is probably a bit too generic for its own good. Also, might be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Also, I should mention, you should read about our expectations in [ask]. You can [edit] for more details.

Comment: @sfdcfox I added a bit more context - I don't think a report would work for what I'm looking to display. The more I think about it, the more I think it will probably have to be visualforce.